# ImageJ Python Scripting

Tags: python, imagej

So I want to make an ImageJ script in Pycharm using Python but I am unable to import the IJ module can anyone help me with the steps I need to take to be able to make a script in Pycharm using

so far I have made the script

```
from ij import IJ
from ij.io import FileSaver
from ij.io import OpenDialog
from ij.plugin import ImageCalculator
import os



IJ.run("Clear Results");

od = OpenDialog("Choose a File", None)
filename = od.getFileName()
directory = od.getDirectory()
path = od.getPath()

imp = IJ.openImage(path)
IJ.run(imp, "32-bit", "")
IJ.run(imp, "Despeckle", "")
IJ.run(imp, "Unsharp Mask...", "radius=2 mask=0.65")
imp.setRoi(486,588,342,1116)
IJ.run(imp, "Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35")
imp.setRoi(0,1,1179,1712)
IJ.run(imp, "ROF Denoise", "theta=6")

imp2 = IJ.run(imp, "Duplicate...","title=imp2")
IJ.run(imp2, "Invert LUT", "")
IJ.run(imp2, "Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=1")
ic = ImageCalculator()
imp3 = ic.run("Add", imp, imp2)

IJ.saveAs(imp3, "jpg", directory)
```

Currently, I have tried to go into the settings of pycharm and tried to download the imageJ package and tried using with `import imagej ij = imagej.init()`

But I get an error which is

````
    import imagej
  File "C:\Users\jorda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\imagej\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .imagej import *
  File "C:\Users\jorda\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\imagej\imagej.py", line 10, in <module>
    import jnius_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jnius_config'```
````

Comment: Hi, @jordan-skinner! Could you provide us with a [minimal repreducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far? What did you do, and what error occured?

Comment: @SvenTUM I updated with more information

Comment: Same problem! The sintax has changed and there is barely information online on the python variant. Using ij=imagej.init() works for me and I don't have your error (though I have another further down the line)